# Mongodb + Split 1 collection + speed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have mongo db on Rails app with multipls collections.
One of the collections has around 0.8 million entries.

I want to devide collection to 4 collections by year it's related (2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), but to keep everything else undevided.

How to do it better?
Can it fasten my queries?
Can I make mongobackup that will only backup 1part of collection + other collections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your queries would always be targeting a specific year, then simply adding an index to your collection on the year field might give you an acceptable performance boost:

```
db.yourCollection.createIndex({"year": 1});
```

If just adding an index alone is not enough, then you look into sharding (horizontal scaling) your Mongo database, using the year as the sharding key.  [See here for more information](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/).  If sharding by year, your Mongo database would then actually consist of some number of vertical shards, each corresponding to one year's worth of data.

Comment: Thank you, trying it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for comment. It solved our problem, I just added indexes and it worked amazing.